# Facing a problem with Google SIPDemo application

Tags: android, sip

I have to build a SIP application for my studies, i maked an Asterisk server, testing it with xlite and all is working. However, i wanted to test it in my Android phone(has 2.3 Gingerbread), i installed the SIPDemo app on it, adding the useful informations and nothing happens, it doesn't indicate if you are connected on the server or not. I run the application in the Android emulator and it saids "Registration failed".
Can you please help me? I really have to make this project to have my diploma.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

from asterisk cli (asterisk -rvvvvvvvvvvv) you should type:

```
sip set debug on
```

and then try to register, this will let you debug the situation.
This could be an asterisk configuration problem or wrong SIP registration management on client's side.
If your registration is successful after removing password from asterisk's user then you need to check how SIP handles registration process https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#page-56 and stick to those rules with your demo.